# Get Facebook Public Feed based on UserLocation or Coordinate

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, userlocation, facebook-public-feed-api

With the help of **graph API** getting **Public Facebook feed** but it's doesn't show **location and place detail**, Need to display only those feed which is **near by user current location**.

**For Eg**, If user is in Atlanta, USA than the user should get only those feed which are in Atlanta, USA.

We also tried with **"https://graph.facebook.com/facebook/feed?&location=33.7677129,-84.420604**" it's doesn't effect the response.
someone please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. There is not functionality to filter a page/user feed by location. You should have a look at the docs.

Furthermore sending requests to `/facebook/feed` is only returning you the posts from the Facebook Page.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed#read